# Override Django allauth signup "next" redirect URL

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

Suppose a user is on the page `/some_url/` on a site with django-allauth. When clicking "Login" they get sent to a URL like:

```
/accounts/login/?next=/some_url/
```

If they are already a registered user, after logging in here, they get sent to the `/some_url/`, which is fine.

But if they're not registered, and they click "sign up", they get sent to:

```
/accounts/signup/?next=/some_url/
```

Suppose I want to send the user to some onboarding experience, at `/onboarding/`, straight after they sign up.

What's the simplest way to override allauth's default behaviour, and send the user to `/onboarding/` even if a `next=/some_url/` is specified?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest way would be to override the template `account/signup.html` with your own copy. If you examine that template you will see the following section:

```
{% if redirect_field_value %}
<input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
{% endif %}
```

If you remove the `if`/`endif` part and change the value inside, the signup page will redirect to a specific page, even if you pass a `next` argument in the URL:

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="/onboarding/" />
```

Comment: Although doesn't fit my case well, it's a good answer. In my case, I'm afraid not all users going to login immediately after signup. Then their URL may still get a "next" parameter. I'm going to use a middleware to do redirection, and use a counter to ensure the redirection only happen once. Ya, complicated solution, but can guarantee "/onboarding/" is visited once

Comment: Would it not be better @Selcuk to do something like `value="{% url 'onboarding_urlname' %}"`

Comment: @unlockme That would be ideal when possible.

Comment: Why not just use name="next" as opposed to name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" If you want a redirect to happen every time for that form?

Comment: @alpalalpal Because `{{ redirect_field_name }}` is _usually_ `next`, but it doesn't have to be. It might have been changed using the `login_required` decorator, for example: `@login_required(redirect_field_name='next_url')`

Comment: +1 for `redirect_field_name` and `redirect_field_value`. Did not realize the `next` variable isn't available in the default `allauth` login view, so the template I had migrated over from Django's default authentication was not working correctly.