# django allauth: redirecting for invalid passwords

Tags: django, redirect, django-allauth

I have a custom page which calls allauth signup view (custom_passcheck.html)

```
<form action="{% url 'account_signup' %}" method="post" class="form">

            {% csrf_token %}
            <BR>
            <BR>
            <BR>
            <center>
                <div class=signuponepage>
                    <div class=sign-up>
                        <div class=signup-box>
                            <div class="form-element email-address">

                                <label id="email-address-label">
                                    <strong>
                                        Create a password (it must be 6 characters long)
                                    </strong>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="{{ pemail }}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ email }}">
                                    <input type="text" maxlength="19" name="password1" value="" placeholder="Password">
                                    <input type="text" maxlength="19" name="password2" value="" placeholder="Password (again)">
                                </label>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-element nextstep-button">
                                {% buttons %}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                        Finish {% bootstrap_icon "chevron-right" %}
                                    </button>
                                {% endbuttons %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>
        </form>
```

Now, if a user puts in password less than 6 chars, it will raise an error and redirect the user to allauth signup page (/account/signup)

Question: instead of redirecting to (/account/signup), how can i redirect to the custom page (custom_passcheck.html) while preserving POST data

Comment: @hadi can you explain further? i dont need a custom signup form per-say for custom fields. i just need to be able to put it in a custom html

Comment: for redirecting, you need a view

Comment: @hadi can you put some example... or references? what you are saying isnt really helping at all

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168337/override-django-allauth-signup-next-redirect-url), i hope this could help you